USB error: " ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 4 comp_code 1"
I'm a beginner to Ubuntu and have been struggling with this issue for a few days. Basically, I am trying to record with an Orbbec Femto Bolt camera, but when I try to actually use the camera, it doesn't do anything. When I ran sudo dmesg, it shows me these errors:
[  140.023726] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 4 comp_code 1
[  140.023731] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000003ca1cc620 trb-start 000000042123c910 trb-end 0000000000000000 seg-start 000000042123c000 seg-end 000000042123cff0
[  140.023732] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000003ca1cc620 trb-start 00000003ca1cc000 trb-end 00000003ca1cc610 seg-start 00000003ca1cc000 seg-end 00000003ca1ccff0
[  140.023733] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 4 comp_code 13
[  140.023735] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000003ca1cc630 trb-start 000000042123c910 trb-end 0000000000000000 seg-start 000000042123c000 seg-end 000000042123cff0
[  140.023736] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000003ca1cc630 trb-start 00000003ca1cc000 trb-end 00000003ca1cc610 seg-start 00000003ca1cc000 seg-end 00000003ca1ccff0
[  140.023737] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: ERROR Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part of current TD ep_index 4 comp_code 13
[  140.023739] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000003ca1cc660 trb-start 000000042123c910 trb-end 0000000000000000 seg-start 000000042123c000 seg-end 000000042123cff0
[  140.023740] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Looking for event-dma 00000003ca1cc660 trb-start 00000003ca1cc000 trb-end 00000003ca1cc610 seg-start 00000003ca1cc000 seg-end 00000003ca1ccff0
[  140.091980] usb 2-2: usbfs: process 2810 (OrbbecViewer) did not claim interface 3 before use

I am on Ubuntu 18.04. I have tried power cycling the PC, unplugging all USB devices, etc. and the errors still come up. Additionally, if I disconnect the device, I start to get these errors in dmesg and I'm not able to connect any device to that port:
[  610.962714] usb usb2-port2: attempt power cycle
[  611.888021] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  616.987443] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  617.095283] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  622.363439] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  622.676007] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  627.739443] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  627.847254] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  633.115433] usb 2-2: device descriptor read/8, error -110
[  633.234777] usb usb2-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

Does anyone know if this is necessarily a software issue or a hardware issue? I'm not sure what's going on. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

What is your USB controller? If it is Asmedia you are probably a victim of the famous "Transfer event TRB DMA ptr not part" problem. I have struggling with it for years. Linux community together with kernel developers tried to fix it in software without success. Finally I gave up on my controller and decided to try controller firmware upgrade. I knew from trusted source that there was firmware upgrade that fix it, but was private so the guy was unable to give it to me. I knew there are firmware leaks on station-drivers site so I gave it a shot. It completely fixed the issue for me.
Looks my last comment here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1749961?comments=all
Good luck
